# C# Identifier as Variable

Tags: c#, json

Situation:
I have a List with around 100 things inside of it. Because I am using JSON and to get a value specific from a json output I use the system.text.json library to first parse, deserialize and to gather the value. Since it are 100+ values I could either make 100+ strings and assign each identifier value to it or (if it is possible) to iterate through a loop that will add the values to the list

Problem:
I now need to make 100 strings and save them to a List afterwards. I want to do this quicker by iterate through the list and but the value as an identifier.

Current Code:

```
string output = response.Content;
            var finaloutput = JsonDocument.Parse(output).RootElement;
            var finaljsonoutput = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(finaloutput);
            ListDetections listDetections = new ListDetections();
            List<string> detectionvalues = new List<string>(listDetections.Detections);
            
            foreach (string value in detectionvalues)
            {
      results.Add(finaljsonoutput.data.attributes.last_analysis_stats.value.something);
            }
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use a loop and place a variable when you try to get a value?
2. Is it better to create 100+ strings to assign a static variable to it?

Comment: 1) `JsonDocument` should be disposed 2) Is there any reason to deserialize into `JsonDocument` first instead of directly deserialazing to `Root`? 3) what is `ListDetections`? 4) What is `Root` ? 5) Please share the json itself. 5) it is not clear what are you trying to achieve and what is a problem here.

Comment: I cannot follow you either

Comment: Agreed. The explanation is confusing imho. A specific example would help.